# Writing vector-membero in minikanren

Tags: scheme, logic-programming, minikanren

I'm trying to write a `membero` equivalent for miniKanren (1) that works on vectors. So far, I can't find a way to do it that doesn't involve observing whether a value is a logic variable or is partially instantiated. Any pointers?

Currently, I've got:

```
(defun rangeo (x n)
  (when (mu-var-p n)
    (error "rangeo must be called with a fully instantiated second argument"))
  (if (<= n 0)
    +fail+
    (conde
      ((== x (1- n)))
      ((rangeo x (1- n))))))

(defun vmembero (x v)
  (when (mu-var-p v)
    (error "vmembero must be called with a partially instantiated second argument"))
  (fresh (i)
    (rangeo i (length v))
    (project (i)
      (== x (aref v i)))))
```

(1): It shouldn't matter, but I'm actually using `cl-kanren`; I don't think anything here should depend on that, though. `cl-kanren` does feature unification of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

To implement this drop back down to scheme. You wont be able to implement it in pure minikanren.

Also you shouldn't be nesting procedure applications inside expressions, like `(== x (1- n))` and `(rangeo i (length v))`. Try to stick to pure logic predicates or pure scheme predicates.

Comment: If I'm implementing this myself, the stream of substitutions produced from `(vmembero ?x ?v)` would look like `?v = #(?x)`, `?v = #(?x ?0)`, `?v = #(?0 ?x)`, `?v = #(?x ?0 ?1)`, ..., right?

Would it make sense then to instead define `(vectoro ?v)` producing `?v = #()`, `?v = #(?0)`, `?v = #(?0 ?1)`, `?v = #(?0 ?1 ?2)`, etc, and `project` the result, then use `rangeo` on the length of the vector, and recurse down through that?

Comment: to be honest you may be better to avoid using vector data type at all in minikanren because it isn't inductively/recursively defined. sticking to lists made up from successive cons cells will work a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to extend our unification algorithm to transparently unify over vectors. You may find that you'll want to transform the representation of terms altogether.